# Setup jest multi projects with create-react-app and node

Tags: node.js, jestjs, create-react-app

My projects uses a `/server` folder for my backend code and `/react-ui` for my client side code. There's a `package.json` in each folder. I can run test separately in the cmd line, but I would like to run both at the same time. I know about the multi projects feature of jest, but it doesn't seem to work with create-react-app. I'm trying to setup jest with babel as if I was not using create-react-app, but it seems like the wrong approach considering jest is already setup in CRA.

My current setup runs from the `/server` jest installation. With `projects: ['<rootDir>', '<rootDir>/../react-ui']`. The jest documentation isn't clear how I could direct it to run `npm test` in `/react-ui`

My only goal is to be able to watch both at the same time and I would like to not eject from CRA.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having the same problem, still searching.

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't seem possible, so I just had to run each test separately each time

Answer (score 0):

You can have (gulp) scripts on the main level that run each tests separately, but using same configs.